# Get column names where column total is greater than 0

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name  Grade  Test1   Test2   Test3
Tim   A        0.7     0.0     0.8
Amy   B        0.8     0.0     0.5
John  B        0.6     0.0     0.6
```

I want to get a list of all the column names with a numeric value that is greater than 0:

```
Test1 # Total would be 2.1
Test3 # Total would be 1.9

# Name and grade ignored as they are not numeric
# Test2 ignored because value is 0
```

How could this be achieved in R?

Comment: A well-formed StackOverflow question will attempt a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.

```r
i <- sapply(df1, is.numeric)
names(df1)[i][colSums(df1[i]) > 0]
#> [1] "Test1" "Test3"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
df1 <- "Name  Grade  Test1   Test2   Test3
Tim   A        0.7     0.0     0.8
Amy   B        0.8     0.0     0.5
John  B        0.6     0.0     0.6"
df1 <- read.table(text = df1, header = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

A solution using `purrr::map_dbl()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  map_dbl(sum) %>%
  {names(.)[. != 0]}

# [1] "Test1" "Test3"
```

Comment: Note that `select_if` has been superseded by other functions. probably better to do `select(where(is.numeric))`

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(Test1:Test3, ~case_when(. > 0 ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>% 
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' ') %>% 
  distinct(New_Col) %>% 
  pull(New_Col)
```

```
[1] "Test1 Test3"
```

Answer (score 4):

What about simply:

```
library(tidyverse)

colnames(select(df1, where(\(x) is.numeric(x) && sum(x) > 0 )))
#[1] "Test1" "Test3"
```

We are just selecting a column if it is both numeric and its column sum is more than zero. Note you need the `&&` instead of `&` so that you don't try to calculate the sum of a non-numeric column.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [@Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76648251/12158757), here are two other base R options

```
> names(df)[sapply(df, \(x) is.numeric(x) && any(x > 0))]
[1] "Test1" "Test3"

> names(which(sapply(df, \(x) is.numeric(x) && any(x > 0))))
[1] "Test1" "Test3"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer with `dplyr` the function `summarize_if` helps to sum only numeric columns.

```
text <-
"
Name Grade Test1 Test2 Test3
Tim A 0.7 0.0 0.8
Amy B 0.8 0.0 0.5
John B 0.6 0.0 0.6
"
df <- read.csv(text = text, sep = " ", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  summarize_if(is.numeric, sum) %>%
  .[, .[1,] > 0]
```